# Getting Stackoverflowexception in query.getInBackground - parse.com android SDK

Tags: android, parse-platform

I always get stackoverflowexception when I try to query a parse.com object based on ObjectID. Has anyone else this problem or is there any workaround to avoid this exception?

(I tried different versions of SDKs, different parse.com accounts - but the exception still exists)

Any help would be appreciated :)

Steps to reproduce:

1) Download sample android starter project
2) Import as existing project using eclipse
3) Fill in app IDs in ParseApplication.java
4) Modify the onCreate method of ParseStarterProjectActivity.java :
   after the ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpened(getIntent()); row add a simple query which is straight from the documentation:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("GameScore");
    query.getInBackground("xWMyZ4YEGZ", new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
      public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
          // object will be your game score
        } else {
          // something went wrong
        }
      }
    });
```

5) Run on a device and wait a few seconds (up to 5-10)
6) Result:  Stackoverflowexception

12-07 13:40:27.298: I/dalvikvm(690): threadid=1: stack overflow on call to Lcom/parse/starter/ParseStarterProjectActivity$1;.done:VLL
12-07 13:40:27.298: I/dalvikvm(690):   method requires 12+20+12=44 bytes, fp is 0x410aa30c (12 left)
12-07 13:40:27.298: I/dalvikvm(690):   expanding stack end (0x410aa300 to 0x410aa000)
12-07 13:40:27.298: I/dalvikvm(690): Shrank stack (to 0x410aa300, curFrame is 0x410ace20)
12-07 13:40:27.298: D/AndroidRuntime(690): Shutting down VM
12-07 13:40:27.298: W/dalvikvm(690): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
12-07 13:40:27.378: D/dalvikvm(690): GC_CONCURRENT freed 307K, 50% free 3050K/6023K, external 410K/517K, paused 2ms+1ms
12-07 13:40:27.418: D/dalvikvm(690): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 284K, 50% free 3130K/6215K, external 410K/517K, paused 14ms
12-07 13:40:27.428: E/AndroidRuntime(690): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-07 13:40:27.428: E/AndroidRuntime(690): java.lang.StackOverflowError
12-07 13:40:27.428: E/AndroidRuntime(690):  at com.parse.starter.ParseStarterProjectActivity$1.done(ParseStarterProjectActivity.java:1)
12-07 13:40:27.428: E/AndroidRuntime(690):  at com.parse.starter.ParseStarterProjectActivity$1.done(ParseStarterProjectActivity.java:1)
12-07 13:40:27.428: E/AndroidRuntime(690):  at com.parse.starter.ParseStarterProjectActivity$1.done(ParseStarterProjectActivity.java:1)
12-07 13:40:27.428: E/AndroidRuntime(690):  at com.parse.starter.ParseStarterProjectActivity$1.done(ParseStarterProjectActivity.java:1)
12-07 13:40:27.428: E/AndroidRuntime(690):  at com.parse.starter.ParseStarterProjectActivity$1.done(ParseStarterProjectActivity.java:1)
12-07 13:40:27.428: E/AndroidRuntime(690):  at com.parse.starter.ParseStarterProjectActivity$1.done(ParseStarterProjectActivity.java:1)
12-07 13:40:27.428: E/AndroidRuntime(690):  at com.parse.starter.ParseStarterProjectActivity$1.done(ParseStarterProjectActivity.java:1)

Additional notes:

- getInBackground with a null callback works, with callback the crash happens in the done part.
- SDK is the latest 1.7.1 but had the same results with 1.5
- Tried the query with real and fake class names, object ids, same results.
- Tried changing the app ids to app ids of a different app , same results.
- Build target can be anything- same results.
- Crashes in simulator
- Devices tested on: Sony Xperia, HTC wildfire
- Eclipse 4.4.1

Comment: Please provide full source code from your `ParseStarterProjectActivity.java`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use findinbackground

```
     ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
            query.whereNotEqualTo("application", null);
            query.whereContains("application", "My App");
            query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {

                @Override
                public void done(List<ParseUser> users, ParseException e) {

             }});
```